# Macro understanding

Tags: c, macros

I've never seen before the following macro format:

```
#define foreach_nat_det_in2out_error                    \
_(UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL, "Unsupported protocol")         \
_(NO_TRANSLATION, "No translation")                     \
_(BAD_ICMP_TYPE, "unsupported ICMP type")               \
_(OUT_OF_PORTS, "Out of ports")                         \
_(IN2OUT_PACKETS, "Good in2out packets processed")
```

Does anybody has ever seen such format? Can you explain what is going on in that code?

Comment: There is nothing special about that macro. Remember that macros are textually replaced at compilation time. If you want more explanations, you need to show us some code that uses this macro. `_` is probably also a macro.

Comment: This is known as an [X macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19588442/3233393) -- though this one arbitrarily uses `_` rather than the usual `X`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I believe I need to dive a little deeper on X macros topic, this is really new for me.

Comment: Can I say that the following format is also a XMACRO:
typedef enum
{
#define _(sym,str) NAT_DET_IN2OUT_ERROR_##sym,
  foreach_nat_det_in2out_error
#undef _
    NAT_DET_IN2OUT_N_ERROR,
} nat_det_in2out_error_t;

Best Regards

Comment: "X macro" isn't anything particularly magical.  It just means a macro whose main purpose is to avoid repetitive typing. It's only used in one place (you usually `#undef` it afterwards) and you give it a very short name like `X` or `_` to save typing.  It's not really worth asking "is this an X macro or not" - just try to figure out what it actually does.